# org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The DataNucleus tool org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer exited with a non-null exit code

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

When running maven build for Google App Engine I am getting a build error:

> org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: The DataNucleus tool
>   org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer exited with a non-null
>   exit code.

I am trying to get Datanucleus working with JDO and data enhancer.

I have followed instructions and have included the following in my pom.xml:

```
  <plugin>
  <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
  <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-release</version>
        <configuration>
          <persistenceUnitName>transactions-optional</persistenceUnitName>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
       <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-release</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-release</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

BTW this is working fine with Java 7 and no build tools. This is a new project with Java 8 and Maven. Getting same error when I run `mvn -X datanucleus:enhance`

Been stuck for days and have tried various iterations of the plugin config and suggestions on Stack Overflow but no luck. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder what the log says, because all DataNucleus docs I've seen say explicitly to look in the log; that will tell you what your problem is, it isn't down to "luck". I wonder why you use v5 of the DataNucleus maven plugin with ancient versions of the DataNucleus jars?!

Comment: perhaps whatever the log says will be something about the JDK being used, and this old version of DataNucleus you use not fully suppporting it? but then that is speculation and unless you look at the log we'll never know ...

Comment: Logs will be more than helpful to solve this issue. Also, I would suggest  using datanucleus-core & datanucleus-api-jdo version 5.0.0-release, unless you have a reason to stick with 3.1.0 (released in 2012)

Comment: I was facing the same issue and was able to get the enhancer worked. But the application fails at run-time now. 
Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/ObjectManager
 at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.newPM(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:630)

Have tried almost everything.Now planning to move to Objectify.

Comment: Hey @thecodecentre , made it working for me. Its absolutely working with Java 8, JDO,App engine. Please share your complete (dependencies) pom.xml.

Answer (score 1):

See, Even I faced the same issue for days and finally realized small things can create big mess. Here you go, at the first instance refer to this link : 
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/maven.html

and use the correct mentioned versions. The problem is, you cannot just use any version of jdo-api, datanucleus-api-jdo & datanucleus-core. These have to be in sync. Please see below I am using :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
     <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

and plugin as :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.maven.plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-m1</version>
            <configuration>
                <api>JDO</api>
                <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                <fork>false</fork>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Few more checks, make sure you have below in your pom :

```
<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0</maven>
</prerequisites>
```

Lastly, run the maven install and see if the enhancer works ! Logs like :

```
 DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.1) : Enhancement of classes.
 DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 2 classes. Timings : input=594 ms, enhance=46 ms, total=640 ms. Consult the log for full details
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) --
```

I have just deployed after new migration changes and it supports the old datastore values in production and works like a charm !Hope it helps !